# C++ - passing an array of unknown size

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Trying to pass an int array of consecutive numbers starting with 1 but assuming the function receiving this array does not know it's length. When trying to calculate the length inside the function it just gives me 1 since it only finds the first element when calculating sizeof(arrayName).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Sum(int intArray[]) {
    int n = sizeof(intArray) / sizeof(*intArray);
    cout << "Array size in function: " << n << endl;
    return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}

int main() {
    int anArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int arraySum = Sum(anArray);

    cout << "Array size in main: " << sizeof(anArray) / sizeof(*anArray) << endl;
    cout << "Sum is: " << arraySum;
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Save yourself the pain, use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Answer (score 16):

Your function is taking a pointer to int. All size information is lost as you pass the array into the pointer. But you can use a function template to instantiate functions that match the right array size:

```
template <size_t N>
int Sum(const int (&intArray)[N])
{
  cout << "Array size in function: " << N << endl;
  return std::accumulate(std::begin(intArray), std::end(intArray), 0);
}
```

This `Sum` function will accept plain arrays or size known at compile time. However, it makes more sense to use `std::array` for these cases, or `std::vector` for cases when the size is chosen at runtime.

Note that the call to `std::accumulate` is just an example that solves the sum problem. It does not require knowledge of `N`, and could replace the function entirely. The size is taken care of by `std::begin` and `std::end`. You would need headers `<numeric>` and `<iterator>` for `accumulate` and `begin/end` respectively.

Comment: +1, and imho, it makes more *"sense"* to use an iterator pair. Oh wait. thats `std::accumulate`. nm =P

Comment: Thanks that does work well passing a consecutive array that starts with 1 then returning N * (N+1) / 2  but can't get it to compile using the accumulate return? Errors say those 3 aren't members of std

Comment: @Instinct `#include <numeric>` and `#include <iterator>`

Comment: hhmm with those includes it's still telling me accumulate/being/end aren't members of std o_O

Comment: @Instinct [It works for me](http://ideone.com/aFNCMt).

Comment: @Instinct I suspect you're not using a C++11 compliant toolchain. Writing your own within the belly of your `Sum` isn't difficult, and in fact can be tailored even to arbitrary types, so long as they support `operator +=` and trivial construction. [See it live](http://ideone.com/OuEugj).

Comment: Are there any performance disadvantages using this template function to accept an array of any size, compared to simply also passing the size of the array to the function? This thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60327543/is-it-bad-practice-to-template-array-sizes-when-calling-methods-that-take-in-arr) seems to go over some of it if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In this function declaration

```
int Sum(int intArray[]);
```

array passed to it as an argument is implicitly converted to the pointer to the first element of the array. So this declaration is equivalent to

```
int Sum( int *intArray );
```

And the expression

```
int n = sizeof(intArray) / sizeof(*intArray );
```

is equivalent to

```
int n = sizeof( int * ) / sizeof( int );
```

if sizeof( int * ) is equal to sizeof( int ) then n will be equal to 1.

If you declare the parameter such a way as you did then you should also declare a second parameter that will accept the number of elements in the array. So I would rewrite the function the following way

```
int Sum( int intArray[], size_t n ) 
{
    int sum = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) sum += intArray[i];

    return sum;
}
```

and in main I would call the function the following way

```
int arraySum = Sum( anArray, sizeof( anArray ) / sizeof( *anArray ) );
```

}

Also functions ususally are written to perform some general algorithms. It is a bad idea to write a function only for arrays that has sequantial values from 1 to some N.