# Is it bad practice to template array sizes when calling methods that take in arrays?

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing an implementation for a neural network, and I am passing in the number of nodes in each layer into the constructor. Here is my constructor:

```
class Network {
   public:
      template<size_t n>
      Network(int inputNodes, int (&hiddenNodes)[n], int outputNodes);
};
```

I am wondering if it is bad practice to use templates to specify array size. Should I be doing something like this instead?

```
class Network {
   public:
      Network(int inputNodes, int numHiddenLayers, int* hiddenNodes, int outputNodes);
};
```

Comment: `std::array` has better syntax than C-array though.

Comment: If you use arrays, why don't you use [std::array<>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead? It is a templated array (both in type and size), which would support your template structure very well.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, and what you want to have as inputs.  For instance the first version will only take an array, while the second will except an array or a pointer.

Comment: The parameter being an array or pointer does not matter to me. std::array looks very useful to me. Thank you!

Comment: why do you think it would be bad practice?

Comment: It depends.   Passing a reference to an array of fixed size (or a `std::array`) means the size must be known at compile time.  Passing a pointer and a size, allows the size to be set at run time (e.g. based on user-supplied  data).    Either way, in both cases, it may be preferable to use standard containers such as `std::array` (array size fixed at compile time) or (for example) `std::vector` (number of elements determined at run time).    Generally, in C++, there are various alternatives to passing arrays or raw pointers around, that can help make it easier to avoid mistakes of logic.

Comment: You even have `std::span` in C++20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates are necessary when you want to write something that uses variable *types*. You don't need it when you just want to pass a value of a given type. So one argument against using a template for this is to keep things simple.

Another problem with the template approach is that you can only pass in a constant value for the size. You can't write:

```
size_t n;
std::cin >> n;
Network<n> network(...); // compile error
```

A third issue with the template approach is that the compiler will have to instantiate a specialization of the function for every possible size you are using. For small values of `n`, that might give some benefits, because the compiler could optimize each specialization better when it knows the exact value (for example, by unrolling loops), but for large values it will probably not be able to optimize it any better than if it didn't know the size. And having multiple specializations might mean the instruction cache in your CPU is trashed more easily, that your program's binary is larger and thus uses more disk space and memory.

So it likely is much better to pass the size as a variable, or instead of using a size and a pointer to an array, use a (reference to an) STL container, or if you can use C++20, consider using [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::span<int>` or write your own.

```
struct int_span {
  int* b = 0;
  int* e = 0;

  // iteration:
  int* begin() const { return b; }
  int* end() const { return e; }

  // container-like access:
  int& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return begin()[i]; }
  std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  int* data() const { return begin(); }

  // implicit constructors from various contiguous buffers:
  template<std::size_t N>
  int_span( int(&arr)[N] ):int_span( arr, N ) {}
  template<std::size_t N>
  int_span( std::array<int, N>& arr ):int_span( arr.data(), N ) {}
  template<class A>
  int_span( std::vector<int, A>& v ):int_span(v.data(), v.size()) {}

  // From a pair of pointers, or pointer+length:
  int_span( int* s, int* f ):b(s),e(f) {}
  int_span( int* s, std::size_t len ):int_span(s, s+len) {}

  // special member functions.  Copy is enough:
  int_span() = default;

  // This is a view type; so assignment and copy is copying the selection,
  // not the contents:
  int_span(int_span const&) = default;
  int_span& operator=(int_span const&) = default;
};
```

there we go; an `int_span` with represents a view into a contiguous buffer of `int`s of some size.

```
class Network {
  public:
    Network(int inputNodes, int_span hiddenNodes, int outputNodes);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

From the way you write the second function argument

`int (&hiddenNodes)[n]`

I guess you're not an experienced C/C++ programmer.  The point is that `n` will be ignored by the compiler and you'll  lose any possibility to verify that the size of the C-style array you'll input here and the `n` passed as the template parameter will be equal to each other or at least coherent with each other.

So, forget about templates. Go `std::vector<int>`.

The only advantage of using a template (or `std::array`) here is that the compiler *might* optimize your code better than with `std::vector`. The chances that you'll be able to exploit it are, however, very small, and even if you succeed, the speedup most likely be hardly measureable.

The advantage of `std::vector` is that it is practically as fast and easy to use as `std::array`, but far more flexible (its size is adjustable at runtime). If you go `std::array` or templates and you are going to use in your program hidden layers of different sizes, soon you'll have to turn other parts of your program into templates and it is likely that rather than implementing your neural network, you'll find yourself fighting with templates. It's not worth it.

However, when you'll have a working implementation of your NN, based on `std::vector`, you can THEN consider its optimization, which may include `std::array` or templates. But I'm 99.999% sure you'll stay with `std::vector`.

I've never implemented a neural network, but did a lot of time-consuming simulations. The first choice is always `std::vector` and only if one has some special, well defined requirements for the data container does one use other containers.

Finally, keep in mind that `std::array` is stack-allocated, whereas `std::vector` is allocated on the heap. Heap is much larger and in some scenarios this is a crucial factor to consider.

EDIT

In short:

- if an array size may vary freely, never pass its value as a
  template parameter. Use `std::vector`
- If it can take on 2, 3, 4, perhaps 5 sizes from a fixed set, you CAN consider `std::array`, but `std::vector` will most likely be as efficient and the code will be simpler
- If the array will always be of the same size known at compile-time,   and the limited size of the function stack is not an issue, use `std::array`.

Comment: About `int (&hiddenNodes)[n]`: Notice that the parameter is a reference. In this case, the array extent *does* matter.

Comment: The `n` will not be ignored. It will be deduced to the correct array size, because the array is taken by-reference. Also Yakk has already given a much better approach than passing a `std::vector` itself. The `std::span` approach accepts `std::vector` and `std::array`, as well as built-in arrays and others.